# Parse a string of 4 numbers into a CGRect

Tags: ios, string, swift

I have this string `(325, 140, 739, 979)` . I want to parse it and take the four numbers separately.

This string represents a `CGRect`. I want to take the first number as `x`  the second as `y` the third as `width` and the last as `height`.

What is the best way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given your string, you can fetch the numbers as an array of optional `Int` like this:

```
let str = "(325, 140, 739, 979)"
let nums = split(str) { contains("(), ", $0) }.map { $0.toInt() }
```

That `split` will remove any of the characters in the string passed to `contains`.  You now have an array of optionals, which you can check for the correct contents:

```
let rect: CGRect
if nums.count == 4,
   let x = nums[0], y = nums[1],
       w = nums[2], h = nums[3]
{
    rect = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: w, height: h)
}
else {
    // report an error, or default the values if you prefer
    fatalError("Malformed input string")
}
```

Any extraneous characters in your input string will result in `nil` for one of the integers, or the wrong count in the array, so this should be safe against any garbage input.

For convenience, you could put all this in a failable initializer for `CGRect`:

```
extension CGRect {
    init?(string: String) {
        // note, since CGRect also has a contains method, need to specify Swift.contains
        let nums = split(string) { Swift.contains("(), ", $0) }.map { $0.toInt() }

        if nums.count == 4,
            let x = nums[0], y = nums[1],
                w = nums[2], h = nums[3]
        {
            self = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: w, height: h)
        }
        else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

let rectangles = [
    "(325, -140, 739, 979)", // valid
    "(1,2,3,asdadaf)",       // invalid (non-integer)
    "1,2,3,4,",              // valid
    "(1,2,3,4,5)",           // invalid (wrong count)
]


// returns an array of 2 valid CGRect and 2 nil
let cgrects = rectangles.map { CGRect(string: $0) }
```

Obviously there’s lots you could tweak here if you wanted to be more or less permissive in terms of the kind of input you’re willing to convert.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution for your case:

```
func parse(str : String) -> [Int] {
        var firstStepStr = str.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "()"))  //remove ( and )
        var secondStepArray =  firstStepStr.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: ", ")).filter{$0 != ""}  //separated by , and ignore ""
        return  secondStepArray.map{$0.toInt() ?? 0}  //convert to [Int], if cannot convert to Int, return 0
    }

let cgrectString = "(325, 140, 739, 979)"
let intArray = parse(cgrectString)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, we could get rid of the parentheses

```
let myString = "(325, 140, 739, 979)"
let myReplacementString = String(map(myString.generate()) {
  $0 == "(" || $0 == ")" ? "-" : $0
})
```

You could also take a substring, which doesn't seem to be any nicer.

Then we could split the string into array

```
var myArray = myReplacementString.componentsSeparatedByString(", ")
```

And then use a loop to cast string to int

```
for item in myArray {
    item.toInt()
}
```

or just use myArray[i].toInt() to give them straight to constructor etc.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you an array of the four CGFloat values you are looking for:

```
func stringToCGFloatArray(string: String) -> [CGFloat] {
    return string.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(
        NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "(), ")).reduce([CGFloat]()) {
        if let x = $1.toInt() {
            return $0 + [CGFloat(x)]
        } else {
            return $0
        }
    }
}
```

You can then convert it to an optional tuple that can be provided directly to `CGMakeRect`:

```
func arrayToRectParameters(array: [CGFloat]) -> (CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat)? {
    switch array.count {
    case 4:
        return (array[0], array[1], array[2], array[3])
    default:
        return nil
    }
}
```

Now you can create a CGRect like this:

```
let str = "(325, 140, 739, 979)"

if let rectParameters = arrayToRectParameters(stringToCGFloatArray(str)) {
    let myCGRect = CGRectMake(rectParameters)
    println(myCGRect)     // prints (325.0,140.0,739.0,979.0)
}
```